# Make a div to the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want the `main-content-root` to go to the bottom of the page. Not shorter and not longer. I look for a solution where the divs before `main-content-root` are not altered. Only css prefered.
Because the menu can vary in height I added some simple code that changes the height of the menu.

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="menu">
    menu  
  </div>

  <div class="main-content-root">
      <div class="content">
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      scroll content<br/>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.root {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  background-color: red;
}

.main-content-root {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {

}


setInterval(function() {$(".menu").css("height", Math.random()*200)}, 1000);
```

Comment: Does getting rid of position:fixed fix your problem? On a jsfiddle the viewer is able to scroll to the bottom after taking out that css

Comment: fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/0j6xzdds/

Comment: @GCyrillus that 'possible duplicate' doesn't even make it to the bottom. I updated it so the body height is 100% so you can see it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/7yLFL/562/

Comment: example down here , you should dig a bit into answer a fixed height 100% or 300px remains a constrain height :) , there was  the answer in the comments too

Comment: @sbswim I tried that with `bottom: 0;` but then it's not relative to the menu anymore.

Comment: you forgot to give  100% height to html,body and section : http://jsfiddle.net/7yLFL/565/

Comment: okay, your fiddle updated with flex: https://jsfiddle.net/0j6xzdds/2/ goodnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex can be used here : do not hesitate to open snippet un full page and play around resizing window :)

```css
html,/* 100% inherited from widow's height , then the cascade will take it to .rrot */
body,
.root{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
 
.menu {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px; /* 200 is too much to show in snippet ... */
}
.main-content-root {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="menu">
    menu
  </div>

  <div class="main-content-root">
    <div class="content">
      scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>scroll content
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now the menu scrolls away, instead of being fixed.

Comment: @clankill3r Hmmm, what funny  browser do you use ? http://caniuse.com/#search=flex  (my mistake, wrong syntax for comments where i tell about inherits height from window)

Answer (score 0):

For a **fixed** [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/1nxzffa7/1/) (Out of the flow):

```
.main-content-root {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

For an **sticky footer** [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ovy5qqn0/2/) (Growing down):

```
html, body, .root {
  height: 100%;
}

.menu {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

For **absolute position** [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/p8byL0wh/) (Growing up):

```
.main-content-root {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your sticky footer but then I get this: https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/0j6xzdds/1/ (menu can't change height anymore and more things are wrong.

Comment: The fixed solution makes the content go over the menu instead of being under the menu.

Comment: And I don't understand the main-content-footer. That will never stick under the menu right?

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning `.main-content-root`. I think the absolute solution will fit you requirements. It's growing up. Make sure that `.root` is **not** `position: relative;`. So it's attaching the position to the `html`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks ok but I doubt it works. The actual website is more complicated due to responsiveness as well. I have been trying for almost 2 weeks now to get it done but fixing one problem always seems to lead to another problem. I think css is fundamentally broken. This is the site of one of the creators of css https://www.w3.org/People/Bos/ check it on a mobile and you laugh your ass off.

Answer (score 0):

if the `main-content-root div`  can have fix height this will work, wrap all your page content in a div

```
<html>
     <body>
        <div class="menu">
            <!-- All the page content -->
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-root">
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

css

```
html{
  position:relative; 
  min-height: 100%;
}

html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.menu{
  margin-bottom:200px; /* Height of main-content-root*/
} 
.main-content-root{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:200px;

}
```